# How to store multiple numpy.ndarray into a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, python-imaging-library

I want to store multiple `PIL.Image` that are converted to `np.ndarray` into `pd.DataFrame` and then store it into a csv file in order to send it to my mlflow model.
How can I load the dataframe just like the dataframe that I saved?
The data type will change after saving into `.csv` format as you can see.

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

img_0 = np.asarray(Image.open("dataset/image_0.jpg"))
img_1 = np.asarray(Image.open("dataset/image_1.jpg"))
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'images': [img_0, img_1],
})
print(df['images'][0])
print(type(df['images'][0]))
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(df['images'][0])
print(type(df['images'][0]))
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'str'>
```

And the data in `df['images'][0]` is changed from

```
[[[ 38  27  23]
  [ 36  25  21]
  [ 33  22  18]
  ...
  [ 30  24  24]
  [ 32  26  26]
  [ 33  27  27]]

 [[ 39  28  24]
  [ 36  25  21]
  [ 33  22  18]
  ...
  [ 30  24  24]
  [ 30  24  24]
  [ 31  25  25]]

 [[ 39  28  24]
  [ 36  25  21]
  [ 34  23  19]
  ...
  [ 29  23  23]
  [ 28  22  22]
  [ 28  22  22]]

 ...
```

to

```
'[[[ 38  27  23]\n  [ 36  25  21]\n  [ 33  22  18]\n  ...\n  [ 30  24  24]\n  [ 32  26  26]\n  [ 33  27  27]]\n\n [[ 39  28  24]\n  [ 36  25  21]\n  [ 33  22  18]\n  ...\n  [ 30  24  24]\n  [ 30  24 ...
```

And the error that I encounter is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/matin/workspace/CI/computational-intelligence-final-project/image_classification_resnet.py", line 158, in <lambda>
    df['images'] = df['images'].apply(lambda x: Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[[ 38  27  23]\n  [ 36  25  21]\n  [ 33  22  18]\n  ...\n  [ 30  24  24]\n  [ 32  26  26]\n  [ 33  27  27]]\n\n [[ 39  28  24]\n  [ 36  25  21]\n  [ 33  22  18]\n  ...\n  [ 30  24  24]\n  [ 30  24
```

Comment: csv is fundamentally a 2d format - rows with a consistent number of columns.  `np.savetxt` can write such a file from a 2d array.  A pandas dataframe is also 2d, so it's `to_csv` works fine.  But if a column contains lists or arrays, it will write a `str` format of that object to that column in csv.  And loading such a file is a pain, possibly even impossible.  Even if you can write a csv, it's no good if you can't also load it.

Comment: `'[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]'` can be `eval` to produce a list.  `'[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]'` is not directly convertible to an array.  And if it also contains '...', the information is lost.